# Dynamic add data to two or more select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try add data dynamic from database with ajax, when i buld edit form with data.
I use modal form named - addForm for adding and editing data, simply I change form data by dynamically.
So when i push edit button, I execute function for build form for edit data **function edtCategory(item)** In this function i insert form data and step by step in select change function, then execute  ajax where i add options from database.

I understand that JS does not have enough time to execute the query and fill in the data when I try to substitute a value in the selection, because of this I had to use this construction with timeout.

Is there another solution to this problem?

```
if ($(editDom).find("#selectcat")[0]) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#selectcat").val(cat_id).change();
        }, 1000);
    }
    if ($(editDom).find("#selectmat")[0]) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#selectmat").val(article_id).change();
        }, 10000);
    }
```

**It's my form**

````
    <label for="selcat">Parent Menu</label>
    <select class="form-control selcat" name="selcat" id="selcat" placeholder="" required>
        <option value="0">Base LVL</option>
    </select>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="form-group field required">
    <label for="seltype">Type Menu</label>
    <select class="form-control seltype" name="seltype" id="seltype" placeholder="" required>
        <option value="0">Link</option>
        <option value="1">Material</option>
        <option value="2">Category</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="forcat" id="forcat"></div>
<div class="forselinput" id="forselinput"></div>```

**JS CODE**

let menu_id = document.querySelector('#menu_id');

function edtCategory(item) {
    var itemId = $(item).parent().children(".nested").attr("id");
    var selcat = $(item).parent().children(".nested").attr("parent_id");
    var seltype = $(item).parent().children(".nested").attr("type");
    var link = $(item).parent().children(".nested").attr("link");
    var cat_id = $(item).parent().children(".nested").attr("cat_id");
    var article_id = $(item).parent().children(".nested").attr("article_id");
    var ItemName = $(item).parent().children("span")[0].innerText;

    let editDom = $(".addMenu");

    $(editDom).find("#mname")[0].value = ItemName;
    $(editDom).find("#menu_id")[0].value = itemId;
    $(editDom).find("#selcat")[0].value = selcat;
    $("#seltype").val(seltype).change();

    if ($(editDom).find("#link")[0]) {
        $(editDom).find("#link")[0].value = link;
    }

    if ($(editDom).find("#selectcat")[0]) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#selectcat").val(cat_id).change();
        }, 1000);
    }
    if ($(editDom).find("#selectmat")[0]) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#selectmat").val(article_id).change();
        }, 10000);
    }

    $(".addMenu").modal("show");
}


function selcatchange(element) {
    if (seltype.value == "1") {
        //get list articles by category ID
        //  document.querySelector('.forcat').innerHTML  = document.querySelector('.forcat').innerHTML + `<div class="form-group field required">
        //         <label for="selectmat">Материал</label><select class="selectmat" name="selectmat" id="selectmat"></select></div>`;
        if (document.querySelector("#selectmat") == undefined) {
            var select = document.createElement("select");
            var lbl = document.createElement("label");
            lbl.setAttribute("for", "selectmat");
            lbl.innerHTML = "Материал";
            select.setAttribute("id", "selectmat");
            select.classList.add("form-control");
            select.setAttribute("name", "selectmat");
            let forcat = document.querySelector(".forcat");
            forcat.appendChild(lbl);
            forcat.appendChild(select);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: `/dashboard/articles/${element.value}/list-articles`,
            method: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("select#selectmat")
                    .empty()
                    .append(
                        data.map(function (element) {
                            return `<option value='${element.id}'>` + element.title_ru + "</option>";
                        })
                    );
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            },
        });
    } else {
        alert(element.value);
    }
}

function LoadSelCat() {
    //Load Category list
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dashboard/category/list",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            function findAllChildren(id, results, depth) {
                for (d in data) {
                    if (data[d].parent_id == id) {
                        data[d].depth = depth;
                        results.push(data[d]);
                        findAllChildren(data[d].id, results, depth + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            var results = [];
            findAllChildren(0, results, 0);
            $("select#selectcat").append(
                results.map(function (element) {
                    return `<option value='${element.id}'>` + Array(element.depth + 1).join(" - ") + element.cat_name + "</option>";
                })
            );
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
    });
}

let seltype = document.querySelector(".seltype");
seltype.value = 0;
seltype.onchange = function () {
    switch (seltype.value) {
        case "0":
            //document.querySelector('.forselinput').innerHTML = ' <label for="link">Link</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="link" required>';
            document.querySelector(".forselinput").innerHTML = "";
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            var lbl = document.createElement("label");
            lbl.setAttribute("for", "link");
            lbl.innerHTML = "Link";
            input.setAttribute("id", "link");
            //input.setAttribute("required", '');
            input.required = true;
            input.setAttribute("type", "text");
            input.classList.add("form-control");
            input.setAttribute("name", "link");
            let forselinput = document.querySelector(".forselinput");
            forselinput.appendChild(lbl);
            forselinput.appendChild(input);

            document.querySelector(".forcat").innerHTML = "";
            break;

        case "1":
        case "2":
            document.querySelector(".forselinput").innerHTML = "";
            document.querySelector(".forcat").innerHTML = "";
            // document.querySelector('.forcat').innerHTML = `<div class="form-group field required">
            //                 <label for="selectcat">Category</label><select class="form-control selectcat" onchange=selcatchange(this) name="selectcat" id="selectcat"></select> </div>`;
            var select = document.createElement("select");
            var lbl = document.createElement("label");
            lbl.setAttribute("for", "selectcat");
            lbl.innerHTML = "Category";
            select.setAttribute("id", "selectcat");
            select.setAttribute("required", "");
            select.setAttribute("onchange", "selcatchange(this)");
            select.classList.add("form-control");
            select.setAttribute("name", "selectcat");
            let forcat = document.querySelector(".forcat");
            forcat.appendChild(lbl);
            forcat.appendChild(select);
            LoadSelCat();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};
````

Comment: Sorry i might have misunderstood your question. Did you tried using `clone` method ? i.e : clone options from select-box which are present inside your addform and add same to your edit form if options are same.

Comment: @Swati I use one form for add and edit data. And when I put data for editing i have problem with select. I'm trying to add a value to a select, and the selects are dependent on each other. If I change the value in the first select, the data is automatically loaded into the next one via ajax, and I am already trying to change the value of this select